# Random Characters At Beginning Of JSON

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to pull some data from an api call, and return it in JSON, as happens perfectly in POSTMAN, I got the successful call, then I used the POSTMAN code for python requests.

However when I run the code in VSCode, the JSON returns with extra characters at the beginning, which stops it being recongnised as JSON. Example below

```
"_ecd: 2.5603\n{\"rates\":[[{\"service_name\":\"Next Day Delivery (Order By 11pm Sun-Fri, 2pm Sat)\",\"service_code\":\"Next Day Delivery (Order By 11pm Sun-Fri, 2pm Sat)\",\"total_price\":199,\"currency\":\"GBP\"},{\"service_name\":\"Standard Delivery (2 to 5 Working Days)\",\"service_code\":\"Standard Delivery (2 to 5 Working Days)\",\"total_price\":99,\"currency\":\"GBP\"},{\"service_name\":\"Premier Delivery\",\"service_code\":\"NEXT_DAY_FREE\",\"total_price\":0,\"currency\":\"GBP\"}]]}"
```

What/why is the "_ecd: 2.5603\n" and how can I stop this from happening?! Surely it should just return the regular JSON without this at the beggining?

Comment: Can you slice off the extra characters? Could you try `response = response[response.index('{'):]`?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: But how did you print out the JSON that you show in your question? You show a string. I must say I *did* assume that you had a string named `response`.

Comment: Actually it might be some server error. You can check a pattern, which in this case seems to be: ignore everything before the first `\n`. So let's say your response is in `resp`, then you can do `json.loads('\n'.join(resp.split("\n")[1:]))`.